# rails 3 No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am newbe to rails3
I have 20 controllers in my rails app..redirecting from one controller to another one my rails app gives  **No Route matches**

should I add  **resources :controllername** entry for each controller in routes.rb file?
or any other general method to do  this?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rake:routes` is your route there?  If it is not you'll get 'No route matches'.  It is much better to use your routes.rb config then to continuously redirect from one controller to another

Comment: dhinesh@dhinesh-ubuntu:~/Rails3/sample$ rake routes
(in /home/dhinesh/Rails3/sample)
root  /(.:format) {:controller=>"cont1", :action=>"index"}
dhinesh@dhinesh-ubuntu:~/Rails3/sample$  is this enough for that?

Comment: But if your route points to a controller, that redirects to a route, is that redirected to route in rake:routes?  This is why doing lots of redirecting can be trouble.

Comment: i have this  entry in routes.rb file `root :to => "cont1#index"`  .. In the file **app/views/cont1/index.html.erb** i have this line `<%=link_to "click_here",{:controller=>"cont2",:action=>"index"}` .. SO running rails app,It gives **No route matches {:controller=>"cont2"}**

Comment: do you see a cont2/index in your rake:routes?

Comment: it would look something like this:   GET    /cont2(.:format)                       {:action=>"index", :controller=>"cont2"}

Comment: no.... I don't have such entry in my routes.rb file. If i add `resources :cont2`, its working fine.. but i can't add this for all controller(I have more than 20 controller)..and each controller have different methods(other then  new,create,edit...)...So how can i get out of this?